# Soundcloud Api Error

Tags: php, api, curl, sdk, soundcloud

I was trying to follow a user using soundcloud api in php.
But I am getting bellow error when i run the code.

> **Warning**: Missing argument 2 for Services_Soundcloud::put(), called in
>   /home/sumithost/public_html/test.php on line 12 and
>   defined in /home/sumithost/public_html/Soundcloud.php on
>   line 636
>
> **exception** 'Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception' with
>   message 'The requested URL responded with **HTTP code 404**.' in
>   /home/sumithost/public_html/Soundcloud.php:941 Stack
>   trace: #0
>   /home/sumithost/public_html/Soundcloud.php(645):
>   Services_Soundcloud->_request('https://api.sou...', Array) #1
>   /home/sumithost/public_html/test.php(12):
>   Services_Soundcloud->put('/me/followings/...') #2 {main}exception

My Code is below

```
require_once 'Soundcloud.php';

$client = new Services_Soundcloud('xxClient-IDxx', 'xxSecretKEYxx', 'http://sumithost.uni.me/sc.php');


$client->setAccessToken('xxAccess-Tokenxx');    


try {
$client->put('/me/followings/3207');
} catch (Services_Soundcloud_Invalid_Http_Response_Code_Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}
?>
```

Using php sdk from here:https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud

*I think error is in put-function of soundcloud.php:636*

Comment: No it is not 3rd Party Library 
I get it from their officicial webiste:  [https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks)

Answer (score 0):

The put method needs a second argument. The description in the docblock comment is wrong.

```
/**
 * Send a PUT HTTP request
 *
 * @param string $path        Request path
 * @param array  $postData    Optional post data
 * @param array  $curlOptions Optional cURL options
 *
 * @return mixed
 *
 * @access public
 * @see Soundcloud::_request()
 */

function put($path, $postData, $curlOptions = array())
```

I think using '' (empty string) as second argument should do the trick.

EDIT: Didn't realize the docblock said its optional. It is not.

Comment: No i want to perform put() operation ,
its showing other arguments as optional.
They are not showing any second argument here also:[https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#follow](
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#follow)

Can you tell me what to provide in second argument if it is required..

Comment: Ah my bad. The comment says optional, but in the code its mandatory. I updated my answer.

Comment: I tried that trick before by that i am not getting warning but i am still getting that exception (given in question)

Comment: Do other requests for this user work? Try to get information about the user by getting the /me endpoint. Perhaps there is something wrong with their demo user?

Comment: i tried get() function its working fine , but getting error in put() function :(
and i do not understand properly what you said..